# QGIS 3.28 set layer styles to defaults after using an older version of QGIS

Tags: qgis, style

As I explained in the heading - when I open a project with QGIS 3.28 (without 3.22), after I have opened it with another version prior to 3.28, for instance 3.16, the styles of the layers are set to default.
Note that for instances - for polygons - all layers are set to blue color (not a random set when you import a layer).

Long story short > I work on a project. I style everything in 3.28. Good so far. Then I jump back to 3.16 for example for a certain feature that is removed in the later version. Then, when I open the project once more in 3.28 - most of the core styles are changed. (Check Notes for further details) > all of the work is lost.

Note 1. It does not apply to version 3.22, because when I work with 3.22 and 3.28 - this bug does not occur.

Note 2. It applies generally to lines and polygons - as all line layers are set default setting 0,26 with color black, all polygons are set to color blue.

Note 3. Transparency settings remain the same.

Note 4. Applies for both Single Symbol and Rule Based symbol styled layers

Note 5. Did not test a lot, but it applies as well to point layer symbols > again sets some of the default settings to 1 specific type.

Does someone know how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I suppose this belongs to the change of backward compatibility of symbology to 3.16 and older which is dropped from now on. This comes with 3.30 and may be it is also in the LTR 3.28.4 and 3.28.5, see https://www.qgis.org/de/site/forusers/visualchangelog330/index.html#breaking-changes

Comment: I assume this is the case. I suppose so as well! I read every version of QGIS changelog, yet I did not meet this change prior to this 3.30 that I did not read so far. Indeed, it might apply to the 3.28.1 that I am using, including 3.26, yet it is not mentioned in these versions. Anyway, for the time being, I accept this as the nature of the issue. Thank you for the link.